# RDP/VNC App that has 1:1 mouse cursor support?

Tags: keyboard, remote-control, remote-access

I've tried a couple different remote desktop programs, but I'm having issues with the mouse support...

For starts, I have to double click everything, even things that are normal a single click, or a single click in the Android OS...

I'm on Archos 101 Android 2.2.1.

I'm pretty familiar with the process of remoting at this point, so my question basically is "which remote desktop solution provides the best experience with a full keyboard, mouse and HDMI support monitor?"

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a physical mouse, or are you just looking for good cursor emulation?  I use Remote RDP Enterprise and I have no problems with the emulated cursor.

Comment: Yes, a physical mouse. All the virtual cursors I use have been acceptable. This seems like an Android operating system issue. Just thought someone might have some tips.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "HDMI support", but i myself use [Teamviewer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.teamviewer.teamviewer.market.mobile&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS50ZWFtdmlld2VyLnRlYW12aWV3ZXIubWFya2V0Lm1vYmlsZSJd).

I have tested lots of programs like this for my android, and my experience tells me that this is the best app for me. I hope you get the same impression.

Answer (score 1):

I use [PocketCloud](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wyse.pocketcloudfree&feature=search_result) and it always seems to do well for me. Although, I haven't tried it a lot with an external mouse.